# converting base 10 to base 2 in prolog

Tags: prolog

am trying to convert base 10 to base 2 using prolog 
this is my code :

```
binary(X,B) :- X > -1 , tobin(B,X,1).
tobin(S,0,1) :- S is 0.
tobin(S,0,V) :- V>1 , S is 1.
tobin(S,X,V) :- X > 0 , 
               X1 is X // 2 , 
               V1 is V * 10 ,  
               tobin(S1,X1,V1),  
               S is X mod 2 , 
               S is S + S1 * V1 .
```

it's not working :/ can you help me ? thank you a lot :D

Comment: "It's not working" is a poor problem statement. You should indicate exactly what you entered, what you expected, and what you saw, particularly any error messages or erroneous results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know what was wrong with you original code, study this:

```
binary(X,B) :- X > -1 , tobin(B,X).
/*tobin(S,0,1) :- S is 0.*/
/* tobin(S,0,V) :- V>1 , S is 1.*/
tobin(0,0).
tobin(S,X) :- X > 0 , 
               X1 is X // 2 , 
               /*V1 is V * 10 ,  */
               tobin(S1,X1),  
               S0 is X mod 2 , 
               S is S0 + S1 * 10 .
```

There are two main changes:

- I've renamed `S` to `S0` in one place as without that one of the statements is always false (`S is S +...`);
- I've removed third argument from `tobin` as it wasn't really necessary to pass positional value to recurrent calls and in all this recurrency some error crept in which wasn't clear to me.

After the fixes your code looks nicer that from @damianodamiano (in my opinion):

```
binary(X,B) :- X > -1 , tobin(B,X).
tobin(0,0).
tobin(S,X) :- X > 0 , 
               X1 is X // 2 , 
               tobin(S1,X1),  
               S0 is X mod 2 , 
               S is S0 + S1 * 10 .
```

Actually, you can skip `binary` and call `tobin` directly (arguments are in reversed order) which makes it even simpler:

```
tobin(0,0).
tobin(S,X) :- X > 0 , 
               X1 is X // 2 , 
               tobin(S1,X1),  
               S0 is X mod 2 , 
               S is S0 + S1 * 10 .
```

Main advantage of @damianodamiano would be runtime optimization by tail recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a predicate to solve your problem:

```
dec2Bin(0,V,_,V).
dec2Bin(N,V,Counter,Val):-
    Reminder is N mod 2,
    N1 is N//2,
    V1 is V + Reminder*(10^Counter),
    Counter1 is Counter + 1,
    dec2Bin(N1,V1,Counter1,Val).

convert(N,V):-
    N > -1,
    dec2Bin(N,0,0,V),
    writeln(V).

?- convert(8,V).
V = 1000.
```